# Remapping the F1 key's functionality to something else (HP laptop, Windows)

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I saw this question asked before on this forum but no one answered it, so I thought I would ask again!

I am using an HP laptop, and when I press the <kbd>F1</kbd> key, it opens up "how to get help in windows 11" on edge ‍♂️.

I keep accidentally pressing it when working and my laptop is kinda slow so it essentially just blocks me from whatever I was doing for a whole 10 seconds, which gets really annoying really fast.

So is there any way to re-map the <kbd>F1</kbd> key to do something else? Ideally, I am looking for a way to re-map it to do anything I want, but if not just disabling the function that opens up "how to get help in windows 11" also works.

I know that Powertoys is an option, but I don't really want to use that since it'll have to always stay open in the background and like I mentioned before, slow laptop, so it'll just impact performance even more.

Someone else who asked another question like this (To disable the WiFi on off option on <kbd>F2</kbd>), got suggested sharpkeys but that just disables the user's <kbd>F2</kbd> key instead of the WiFi on off function.

Then finally, I do not want to enable the function that makes me press the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key with the <kbd>F1</kbd> key to make it do the function, since I use all the other <kbd>F2</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> keys like backlighting, volume, media control and brightness very often, and it'll make using those much more annoying which isn't worth it.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

The other guy who asked this question got an answer on how to disable the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key or <kbd>F1</kbd> key instead, and to be clear I am not asking to disable the key! I am asking to disable the functionality that opens up a help page on edge when the key is pressed, and either replace that with something else or remove it entirely.

Comment: For nuisance keys, such as CAPS LOCK, I carefully shove a small bit of plastic foam under the edge of the key cap. A little extra pressure and the key functions normally.